# How do I use the 'scientific' mode in the Calculator?

Tags: calculator, gcalctool

I am trying configure the *Calculator* to do some binary to hexadecimal conversions but I can't seem to get to scientific mode. Please can someone tell me how I configure?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The **Calculator** has various modes. What you are looking for is the **Programming mode**, which lets you display numbers in various bases. To use it, select **Calculator › Programming** from the menu.

As you asked for the *scientific* mode, I must add that functions commonly used in scientific calculations are available using **Calculator › Advanced**.

[image]

Comment: Does it support combinations and permuation